# Dynamic redirecting pages in Django with regular expressions?

Tags: python, django, url-routing

I have problem with *url.py* in django.

In my app i have many urls like:

```
aaa-2011-bbb
aaa-2011
```

and i would like redirect these urls to new url without year. So i need remove year from url. Is it possible?

I have only static mapping like this:

```
(r'^aaa-\d{4}-bbb/$', redirect_to, {'url': '/aaa-bbb/'}),
```

but i don't like write this rule for every url with year.

Comment: any good reason you have the year in url if you don't want to use it?

Comment: @Hoff: There could be many reasons for this being out of the original poster's control, maybe he has SEO guys deciding on the URLs etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @danodonovan mentioned, [*RedirectView*](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/class-based-views/#redirectview) is the best way to achieve this.

However, to avoid further unnecessary repetition I propose the following:

```
# urls.py
(r"^([^/]*?(19|20)\d{2}[^/]*?)/?$", RemoveYearRedirect.as_view()),

# views.py
from django.views.generic.base import RedirectView
import re

class RemoveYearRedirect(RedirectView):
    query_string = True

    def get_redirect_url(self, **kwargs):
        """
        This has been overriden to remove any year from 1900 to 2099 from the URL
        """
        url = re.sub("(19|20)\d{2}", "", self.args[0])
        return "/" + re.sub("-+", "-", url).strip("-")
```

This should work with URLs like:

- /testing-2012-foo --> /testing-foo
- /2000-never-happened --> /never-happened
- /movies-from-1960 --> /movies-from

Comment: But it's not ok, because it has loop like this:     `/testing-2012-foo --> /testing-2012-foo/testing-foo --> /testing-2012-foo/testing-foo/testing-foo `

Answer (score 2):

I would subclass [`RedirectView`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/class-based-views/base/#redirectview) and use that to power a dynamic redirection

`urls.py` something like

```
(r'^(?P<aaa>\w+)-\d{4}-(?P<bbb>\w+)/$', MyRedirectView.as_view()),
```

and in `views.py`

```
from django.views.generic.base import RedirectView

class MyRedirectView(RedirectView):
    permanent = False
    query_string = True

    def get_redirect_url(self, aaa, bbb):
        return '%s-%s' % (aaa, bbb)
```

This takes the `**kwargs` `aaa` and `bbb` from the `urls.py` (assumed to be strings and from the url redirect you describe) and returns a redirect url composed `'%s-%s' % (aaa, bbb)`

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do the same using less code:

```
(r'^(?P<aaa>\w+)-\d{4}-(?P<bbb>\w+)/$', RedirectView.as_view(url='%(aaa)s-%(bbb)s')),
```